# img of admin auth doesn't loading in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**i am trying to show the image of the admin user but no thing show .
. and  name  email of the user showing correctly**

```
@php
$adminData = Auth::user();
@endphp


< div class="widget-user-header bg-black" >
                          <h3 class="widget-user-username">Admin Name : {{ $adminData->name }}</h3>
                          <a href="{{route('admin.profile.edit')}}" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success mb-5"> Edit Prfile</a>
                          <h6 class="widget-user-desc">Email : {{ $adminData->email }}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-user-image">
     <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{(!empty(asset($adminData->profile_photo_path) ))? url('upload/admin_images/'.$adminData->profile_photo_path):url('upload/no_image.jpg')}}">
                        </div>
```

Comment: instead ```url()``` try with ```asset('/path')```

Comment: May I ask what is the value of `$adminData->profile_photo_path`? It seems it is including the `upload/admin_images/` based on @A.A Noman 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like below

```
@if($adminData->profile_photo_path)
    <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{url('/'.$adminData->profile_photo_path)}}">
@else
     <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{url('/no_image.jpg')}}">
@endif
```

Comment: the image doesn't work but when i make inspect in browser i see src imge like that 
it is duplicated upload/admin_images/upload/admin_images 
must be upload/admin_images/
src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/admin_images/upload/admin_images/1708201127288382.jpg"

Comment: It happens because of tersian operator issue may be. Better use `if else` condition I think

Comment: how i write that please

Comment: syntax error, unexpected token ";", expecting ")"

Comment: @ALAAELDIN, I updat my answer

Comment: yes it is still duplicated   admin_images/upload/admin_images
src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/admin_images/upload/admin_images/1708201127288382.jpg"

Comment: @ALAAELDIN, I understand your problem. I edit my question again

Comment: src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/admin_images/upload/admin_images/1708201127288382.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

You Can check if admin photo contains null value or not

```
<img class="rounded-circle" src="{{$adminData->profile_photo_path != null? url('upload/admin_images/'.$adminData->profile_photo_path):url('upload/no_image.jpg')}}">
```

Comment: the image doesn't work but when i make inspect in browser i see src imge like that 
it is duplicated upload/admin_images/upload/admin_images 
must be upload/admin_images/
src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/admin_images/upload/admin_images/1708201127288382.jpg"

Comment: Then you can use <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{$adminData->profile_photo_path != null? url($adminData->profile_photo_path):url('upload/no_image.jpg')}}">

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it like this. Make sure you have a default image like no_image.jpg as a fallback function. It does display the image in case if the `profile_photo_path` attr exists or falls into `no_image` if not. However, I think your issue is because you don't point to `storage` folder.

```
<img src="{{ storage_path($adminData->profile_photo_path ?? 'admin_images/no_image.jpg')) }}" />
```

Comment: yes it is still duplicated   admin_images/upload/admin_images
src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/admin_images/upload/admin_images/1708201127288382.jpg"

Comment: Just edited the answer! make sure you have `admin_images` folder in your storage